# Variable substitution in TCL within curly brace

Tags: tcl

I'm having a problem where variables are in curly brace.I am trying to perform a variable substitution within curly braces which I understand is not feasible directly in TCL.But if there are other methods to resolve this? because I see the samiliar question in website that the answer is use list [] and others. But I want to countinue use curly brace, could someone can help me to resolve the question?

```
set top_design a
puts $top_design
puts {aaa %top_design}
```

output :

```
 a
 aaa %top_design
```

so how to display the subtitute of top_design in second puts.

Comment: There's no variables in `puts {aaa %top_design}` to substitute...

Comment: The usual method would be `puts "aaa $top_design"`, why do you insist on using `{}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the `%` typo, you're looking for the [`subst`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm) command:

```
set top_design a
puts {aaa $top_design}          ;# => aaa $top_design
puts [subst {aaa $top_design}]  ;# => aaa a
```

There are options to `subst` so that you have control over which things get substituted:

```
% puts [subst {aaa $top_design\n[clock seconds]}]
aaa a
1666273294
% puts [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {aaa $top_design\n[clock seconds]}]
aaa a\n[clock seconds]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I think subst can sesolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have messed up a little while forming the question.
In Tcl, { and } have special meaning, you can simpy say that this is an escape sequence or a list - depending on where it is used.

Let's see the following simple example:

```
set v1  aaa
set v2  bbb
set vres1 {$v1 $v2}
set vres2 "\{$v1 $v2\}"
set vres3 "\{\$v1 \$v2\}"
set vres4 {{$v1 $v2}}
```

This will result in the following output:

```
% set vres1 {$v1 $v2}
$v1 $v2
% set vres2 "\{$v1 $v2\}"
{aaa bbb}
% set vres3 "\{\$v1 \$v2\}"
{$v1 $v2}
% set vres4 {{$v1 $v2}}
{$v1 $v2}
```

For vres1, you have variables not evaluated as {} were used as an escape sequence.
For vres2, braces are escaped so are treated as a standard character, thus "" are needed to properly  set all the characters as one argument for set command. Note that v1 and v2 are evaluated here as {} are not escape characters but characters that we are just saving in variable.
For vres3, we did manual escaping of braces and $ so that variables are not evaluated and braces are part of the string.
For vres4, first set of braces are escaping the second set and also $.

Now I guees, that you already have something like vres3 or vres4 and you want to get the values of the variables in braces.
When you have nested variables, you should use the eval command like below:

```
% eval set out1 \"$vres1\"
aaa bbb
% eval set out2 \"$vres2\"
{aaa bbb}
% eval set out3 \"$vres3\"
{aaa bbb}
% eval set out4 \"$vres4\"
{aaa bbb}
```

I hoped it helped in your issue!

[Ufff, my first answer!]

Comment: There is no need to escape the curly braces in your vres2 and vres3 commands. Curly braces are only special at the start of a word. So `set vres2 "{$v1 $v2}"` will also set vres2 to `{aaa bbb}`.

Comment: Sure, I do agree. I was only trying to give some wider scope on creating the string and their format as this was not clear (to me) in the original question.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know the new command eval now.

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl 8.7, you'll be able to do this:

```
set top_design a
puts $top_design
set input {aaa %top_design}

puts [regsub -all -command {%(\w+)} $input {apply {{- varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName var
    # Ignore case where variable doesn't exist
    return $var
}}}]
```

The key thing is that `%top_design` isn't very special at all to Tcl code; the `%` symbol is only meaningful in a few contexts (`format`, `clock`, `expr`, and Tk's `bind`). For it to have any other meaning, you have to apply that meaning yourself. That gets much easier with `regsub -command` (a new feature in 8.7) since that lets you use a command to generate the substitution within a `regsub`; that pairs well with `apply` though you could use a procedure instead. In earlier versions, such substitutions required non-trivial quoting and `subst`; I always found those things difficult to write correctly.